# What's happening in queryset converting to list

Tags: django, mongodb

I have some problem in using methods in mongoengine,just as follows (just show the key codes ):

```
 from mongoengine import *

 class AB(Document):
      ........

 queryset=AB.objects(__raw__=rawquery)
 num1=queryset.count()
 querylist=list(queryset)
 num2=len(querylist)
```

The problem is that in my project num1=111 ,however num2=55

my question is why num1 < num2 ?

what is happening in the code `"querylist=list(queryset)"`?

thank u!

Comment: most likely, the underlying datastructure is a string in the database, which is causing this. In string coersion, `111` is less than `55`

Comment: but why the number of records decreases ,after using the list() to covert the queryset to list?

Comment: are you sure? did you try `len()` or just printing to console ?

Comment: sure,I run the project ,and i hit log which shows the num2=55 and the num1=111.